# how to create a generic return type in java

Tags: java, return-type

Hi i have following scenario in java:
I have got lots of classes each class has got lots of methods. now today this methods are returning integer(Note: all methods are returning some computed value as integer). Tomorrow this methods could return the same computed value as string or any other data type(like long,etc. ). now it would be a cumbersome effort to go and change the return type of each and every method to the desired return type. [Note: this scenario is because i am under framework development and my framework is as of now not stable so things like this keep changing]. i was wondering is this possible or not, to create a return type which as of now will point to integer and then use this return type in every method so tomorrow if i were to change in the return type of this method then i just need to change at one particular place and automatically the return type will change? Any pointers on this. TIA.

Comment: The question title should be edited to be more accurate.

Comment: This seems like the kind of problem that can be solved by a regex find/replace or other kind of simple script.

Comment: You seem to be getting the cart ahead of the horse here. You need to decide on your code structure before you can type out any code.

Comment: To give you guyzz a valid scenario lets say you have a calculator which today returns integer values tomorrow all the methods of calculator may return long values, going ahead it may also return big integer. so it will be a stupidity to go and manually keep changing all the return types.

Comment: A calculator that returns integers would not be very useful. All you could do as add and subtract. Your calculator should do the calculations in the most general format. Then you can add different getter methods, like getIntValue(), getDoubleValue(). So you would need to convert the general format to the specific format.

Comment: Even if you did manage to do it, it would only *move* your problem instead of solving it. Instead of having to change the method signatures of a bunch of methods, you would have to go in to each method and change the logic to make it return the correct thing. More than that, suppose someone is using your framework and wrote code expecting an int. Then you change it to now return a long. That breaks their code. Your best bet if you NEED to change things like that is to make a new method and deprecate the "current" ones.

Comment: First of all as Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested, we design first and code it after that, if its not the way you are proceeding when you talk about changing returntype, you will have to change the data processing of the function as you can not process a String the way you process Integer. Though for temporary solution you can set Object as a return type and cast returned value in your function(as you are knowing what is getting returned) but again, its not advisable to do so, it can be accepted only as a temporary solution.

Comment: Guyzz instead of pointing nooks into my framework can we stick to the issue which i am facing. can anyone tell me if this is possible or not. please do not worry about my framework and its usage that is my headache. can anyone of you suggest something about this requirement.

Comment: The headache is because your question is in fact an example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking for, no demanding, a specific solution for a problem when the real issue, that being the true underlying problem, goes ignored. I have a feeling that the best most of us will get here is to agree to strongly disagree.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want generics, but the caveat is there's no magic to transform the type returned from your coded methods, only the *definition* of what they return:

```
public interface Calculator<T> {
    public T method1();
    public T method2();
    public T method3();
}

public class IntegerCalculator implements Calculator<Integer> {
    public Integer method1() [
        // some implementation that returns an Integer
    }
    // similar for method2 and method3, which also return Integer
}

public class LongCalculator implements Calculator<Long> {
    // similar to IntegerCalculator but all methods return Long
}
```

And your client could define their code to use:

```
Calculator<Integer> = new IntegerCalculator();
```

but later change to

```
Calculator<Long> = new LongCalculator();
```

You would have to still code the methods for all type implementations you want to use, and your client code would likewise have to be altered to work generically, but this is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic method like this:

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String []areg){
     NewClass nc = new NewClass();
     nc.getObject(new Integer(123));
     nc.getObject("abc");
     nc.getObject(new Long(2));
    }

  public <T> T getObject(T type)
  {
  return type;
 }
}
```

in your calling code, you can check the returned type and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only return type of methods. If you want to return a big integer at some point, you would also need to change your method code to actually compute such a value. Also your `return` statement would need changing, not only method signature.
If you keep computing an integer in the method, then it makes no sense to return BigInteger. So how could a tool refactor your code and every place it is used?

The best thing I can see is if you are using a Java IDE, once you change your method signature it will output errors for you where there is a type mismatch and you can go through these errors and fix things manually.

I am guessing your project is small, for big projects such refactoring would be unmanageable anyways...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class. It is your User-Definition-Type. 
such as :

```
public class ReturnType {
private Object value;

public ReturnType(Object value){
    this.value = value;
}

public Integer getIntValue(){
    if(value instanceof Integer)
        return (Integer)value;
    return null;    
}
public Long getLongValue(){
    // todo 
}

public String getStringValue(){
    //todo
}
```

}

return type of your methods should be an instance of 'ReturnType' class.

Like:

```
    public ReturnType myMethod();
```

In the another times you can add / remove or modify the methods in ReturnType class.

Comment: hi Vahid i tried your solutions but i am stuck at this place. Ok let me tell you the real scenario. I am designing a UI Framework. today my framework uses Selenium WebDriver so all my methods as of now return WebElement. Now tomorrow i might move to Sahi and all my methods need to return BrowserElement. So that why i have to do this thing. now if i go by your solution i am not able to use the methods WebElement interface. Can you suggest me something for this? If i can somehow create a pointer to WebElement and then use that pointer instead of WebElement so that tomorrow i may point it to Sahi